# visual studio macro or Regex to remove try-catch blocks?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know of a visual studio macro to remove try-catch blocks? Or the regex to find-replace these try catch blocks?

Or if you can show how to create one, that would also be great.

Answer (score -2):

It would remove the try-catch blocks, and then what? Exceptions are used for error handling, so just removing them would remove the error handling from the code.

I've never heard of such a tool (although I once heard of one that turned return codes into exceptions). It would not be trivial, because error handling is not trivial. And it would certainly be more difficult (if not impossible) to turn exceptions into return codes or something else.

Comment: Questioning the question is not an answer. There are valid reasons to want to remove try-catch blocks in a piece of code. For example, I have taken over a codebase where every exception is caught and then rethrown wrapped in another exception, which hides the original source in the stack trace - extremely inconvenient.

Comment: Amen @AlexFoxGill. Yes there are some with a naive understanding of try-catch blocks, especially considering performance implications. For everyone's reference, here's MSDN's Best Practices for Exception handling at msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Another reason to remove try-catch blocks is if they are unnecessary. E.g. in JavaScript `try {} catch (err) throw err;` is unnecessary from an async function as the error will propagate without the try-catch. This can become more of an issue in JavaScript if recommended linting rules have been updated to prevent unnecessary try-catch.